# Linq Joined Table Record Delete

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a question about linq delete.

I have 2 table in database and they are joined.

First Table: UserID, UserName, UserSurname, UserPhone, CompanyId

Second Table: CompanyId, CompanyName

First Table I have many recods with related second table.

I want to delete one company in second record, But firtly I have to delete users (more than 1)

How can I delete it with using linq?

Thanks John,

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to delete a User record, and have the associated Company record(s) deleted as well. Probably the easiest way to do this is to set up the foreign key in your database to be a cascading delete foreign key. Then just use Linq to delete the User records you want to delete. The associated Company records will be deleted automatically by SQL Server.

Comment: thanks Randy. But How can I do this cascading delete? Can I remove relation?

Comment: @John - You want to do the cascading deletion yourself? Why would you want to do this? Let the database do the heavy work. It's much more efficient.

Comment: @John - use the following syntax: ALTER TABLE XXX ADD CONSTRAINT FK_XXX FOREIGN KEY (XXX) REFERENCES XX(XXID) ON DELETE CASCADE GO

Answer (score 0):

you may use this

```
var toDelete = from c in yourDataContext.Companies
               where c.ID = 1
               select c

yourDataContext.Users.DeleteAllOnSumbit(toDelete .Users);
yourDataContext.Companies.DeleteOnSumbit(toDelete );
yourDataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

for farther help please let me know.

Comment: Thanks Rami. Bu I can not use c.Users because of c is not declared. If I try to use toDelete.Users it is giving error :(

Comment: toDelete.Users -> users I can not use it because it is giving an error when I use it. Like this:                      'System.Linq.IQueryable<User>' does not contain a definition for 'Users' and no extension method 'Users' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<User>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: do you set the relation between company and user in the ORM (.dbml) file?

Comment: Click on the relation link and go to properties pane and see what its name. then use it in instead of `Users`